# Crash while retrieving data from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase

My Code

```
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("PostInfo")
    let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "post_title").queryEqual(toValue: self.retrieve_title)
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
       print((snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "status").value as? String)!)
    }
}
```

jSon Data

```
     {"PostInfo":{
   "-KyjkkEAZeHLjdRLg20w" : {
       "postImage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/hobbyquest-ee18d.appspot.com/o/8C40BA04-6D8D-4A23-B8BB-E1B3AC64E66F.png?alt=media&token=3f0f10e3-a64b-4187-9259-3c25bfc4a9e5",
       "post_title" : "hahahahah",
       "status" : "a banana an",
       "threadForHobby" : "Bowling",
       "userID" : "ccuvHt6feYVIO6GUXKo3OpO6VUn2"}
       }
```

I am trying to get the status data from firebase but the app keeps crashing. Please help!

Comment: Add the code not the photo of your code

Comment: Might it be that your saying 'ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "post_title")' and there is no 'post_title" child in PostInfo there is only '-KyjkkEAZeHLjdRLg20w'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "status").value as? String)!
```

Your code is reading the data by .value.

.value returns ALL nodes within the given node and you will need to iterate over them. For example. Suppose our database looks like the following and you are querying for posts with a post_title of title_0

```
PostInfo
  post_0
    postImage = "www.thing.com"
    status = "status_0"
    post_title = "title_0"
  post_1
    postImage = "www.yipee.com"
    status = "status_1"
    post_title = "title_1"
  post_2
    postImage = "www.dude.com"
    status = "status_2"
    post_title = "title_0"
```

When running your query, both post_0 and post_2 will be returned because they both have title_0

You would need to iterate over the snapshot to get the results.

```
    let ref = self.ref.child("PostInfo")
    let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "post_title").queryEqual(toValue: "title_0")
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let x = (snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "status").value as? String)!
            print(x)
        }
    }
```

If you notice - your line of code works in this scenario because it's examining each child as a separate snapshot.

On the other hand, if you only want to return the first match, you can use .childAdded, which will return just an individual node:

```
    let ref = self.ref.child("PostInfo")
    let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "post_title").queryEqual(toValue: "title_0")
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            let x = (snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "status").value as? String)!
            print(x)
    }
```

Comment: Great explanation Jay!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but you could do it a different way but changing the layout of your data.

The data would be like this:

```
{"PostInfo":{
   "searchidentifier" : { //whatever identifier you want, I think you're trying to use the post title
          "object" : {
              "postImage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/hobbyquest-ee18d.appspot.com/o/8C40BA04-6D8D-4A23-B8BB-E1B3AC64E66F.png?alt=media&token=3f0f10e3-a64b-4187-9259-3c25bfc4a9e5",
              "post_title" : "hahahahah",
              "status" : "a banana an",
              "threadForHobby" : "Bowling",
              "userID" : "ccuvHt6feYVIO6GUXKo3OpO6VUn2"}
   }
 }
```

And you would retrieve your data like this:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("PostInfo").child("\(self.retrieve_title)")

ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
     if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
           for classes in snapshot.children.allObjects as![FIRDataSnapshot] {
               let classesObject = classes.value as? [String: AnyObject]
               let postImage = classesObject?["postimage"]
               //Retrieve all the other objects here as well
            }
      }
})
```